# Removing quotes of string in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%
    String val = request.getParameter("name");
%>
```

Above `val` contains a value like `{ "name":"a"}`. I need to escape the quotes in order to place it inside a text field like below.

```
<input type="text" name="firstVal" value="<%=val%>"/>
```

I have tried `jstl` function but this did not help.

Comment: What about `value='<%=val%>'`?

Comment: This worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

How about replace it first before displaying it on your jsp like

```
String val = request.getParameter("name").replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Then replace it again if you need it as a json format.